# Prism5 PopupWindowAction and injection

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

I looked at part of InteractivityQuickstart official example.

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ItemSelectionRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction>
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <views:ItemSelectionView />
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

So, ItemSelectionRequest called less-parametre constructor

```
public ItemSelectionView()
{
    this.DataContext = new ItemSelectionViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

in code-behind of ItemSelectionView.

Questions:
1) How possible to set DataContext without "new", because

```
public ItemSelectionView(ItemSelectionViewModel model)
```

or

```
[Dependency]
public ItemSelectionViewModel ViewModel
{
    set { this.DataContext = value; }
}
```

doesn`t work.
I need to get some services in ViewModel => i need to call something like this

```
public ItemSelectionViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    _eventAggregator=eventAggregator;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a service for your Popup ViewModel, you could get it by using the ServiceLocator.

```
public ItemSelectionView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ItemSelectionViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! But i got small issue: this popup should raise after moment when shell loaded, its something like login form, so a raise it on "Loaded" event on shell(=after CreateShell() in BootStrapper). With prism`s services all right, but problem occured with shared services, because modules loaded after CreateShell() and i get exception. What is the good plactise how to raise popup after shell loaded?

Comment: Please mark this as the answer for this specific issue, and then ask your other question as a separate post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the ServiceLocator to set your ViewModel as Brian Lagunas suggests, why not have a parameterless constructor for ViewModel, set the ViewModel directly in your View class (XAML or code-behind), and use the ServiceLocator within the ViewModel itself to get the services (or their interfaces) your ViewModel needs? I suggest this for two reasons:

- Using the ServiceLocator in the constructor of the View for the popup will give you an error of "ServiceLocationProvider must be set" at design time within the "prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent" section. (Though it works fine at runtime.)
- You've already been forced into a situation where you have to bypass dependency injection in some manner, so why not simplify the code, particularly if you only need access to one service anyway.

So you can do something like this:

```
public ItemSelectionViewModel()
{
    _eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
}
```

And if you only need to use the IEventAggregator object once, there's no reason to even assign it to a field. Just use the ServiceLocator call where you need to get the Event Aggregator and remove your explicit constructor entirely.

Comment: I have gone away from PopupWindowAction)